# Unit testing methods in the Presenter, MVP

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, moq, mvp

Im trying to test a method which composes a collection of controls. It calls two methods:

1. Copies the original collection.
2. Sorts the new collection.

Ideally id like to be able to pass in a collection and test to see thats it sorts it correctly. Id also like to verify that method 1) is called twice, see below attempt based on the following:
[Example using RhinoMock](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/unit-testing-the-presenter-in-an-mvp-context-using-mock-objects)

The following test is producing errors when i try to create an instance of MainPresenter. General jist of the errors are "Can not convert from Moq.Mock to "FrazerMann.CsvImporter.UserInterface.IMainForm. + a similar one for IFileDialog.

```
    [Test]
    public void ComposeCollectionOfControls_CallSequence_4Calls()
    {
        var main = new Mock<IMainForm>();
        var dialog = new Mock<IFileDialog>();
        var temp = new Mock<IMainPresenter>();

        temp.Setup(s => s.PopulateLists<Control>(It.IsAny<TableLayoutPanel>(), It.IsAny<List<Control>>()));

        var testObject = new MainPresenter(main.Object, dialog.Object);
        testObject.ComposeCollectionOfControls(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<EventArgs>());
        temp.Verify(v => v.PopulateLists<Control>(It.IsAny<TableLayoutPanel>(), It.IsAny<List<Control>>()), Times.Once());          
    }
```

I would like to test the ComposeCollectionOfControls to ensure PopulateList() is called twice.

```
public interface IMainPresenter
{
    void PopulateLists<T>(TableLayoutPanel userInputs, List<T> container) where T : Control;
    int SortList<T>(T control1, T control2) where T : Control;
}

public class MainPresenter:IMainPresenter
{
    UserInputEntity inputs;

    IFileDialog _dialog;
    IMainForm _view;

    public MainPresenter(IMainForm view, IFileDialog dialog)
    {
        _view = view;
        _dialog = dialog;
        view.ComposeCollectionOfControls += ComposeCollectionOfControls;
        view.SelectCsvFilePath += SelectCsvFilePath;
        view.SelectErrorLogFilePath += SelectErrorLogFilePath;
        view.DataVerification += DataVerification;
    }

    public void ComposeCollectionOfControls(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateLists<TextBox>(_view.ColumnNameCtrls, _view.SortedColumnNameCtrls);
        _view.SortedColumnNameCtrls.Sort(SortList<TextBox>);
        PopulateLists<ComboBox>(_view.ColumnDataTypeCtrls, _view.SortedColumnDataTypeCtrls);
        _view.SortedColumnDataTypeCtrls.Sort(SortList<ComboBox>);
    }
}
```

Could someone please give me some pointers as to how this should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because your are passing the mock class itself (which is of type `Moq.Mock`) rather than the mocked object that Moq creates for you.

Instead of:

```
var testObject = new MainPresenter(main, dialog);
```

you need:

```
var testObject = new MainPresenter(main.Object, dialog.Object);
```

---

As an aside, it is usually considered bad practice to explicitly verify things like the number of calls made on a particular method. This leads to a tight coupling between your tests and a particular implementation, and consequently brittle tests.

By testing how many times you call a method you will often find a test failing after you refactor some code when the end result of the code is still correct.

It is much better to test the final state of the objects involved, and make your tests ignorant of how that state was reached.

Comment: face-palm! Thanks very much David

Comment: Thanks very much for the edit to your original answer, i wasnt aware of that. Out of curiosity (This is the reason i had the eventhandler call a separate method, but u mentioned yesterday this was wrong so im assuming im making a stupid mistake), im getting a null object error which im assuming is due to this line  "testObject.ComposeCollectionOfControls(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<EventArgs>());" is it not possible to use It.IsAny<Object>() to fill in for sender/e?